# How to configure netflix dgs?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle-kotlin-dsl, netflix-dgs

This is a really simple question, but hard to find the answer.

I'm using kotlin DSL and gradle (so `build.gradle.kts` and `settings.gradle.kts`).

I'm using netflix-dgs and spring boot like so:

`implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")`
`implementation("com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-spring-boot-starter")`

And of course a few others (e.g. extended scalars).

I've figured out how to edit my `generateJava` task:

```
tasks.withType<com.netflix.graphql.dgs.codegen.gradle.GenerateJavaTask> {
    schemaPaths = mutableListOf("$projectDir/src/main/resources/schema")
    packageName = "envoy.roomba.netflix.dgs.generated"
}
```

How do I edit the rest of the configuration mentioned here? https://netflix.github.io/dgs/configuration/.

I tried a `gradle.properties` file, I've looked briefly at extending `@DgsAutoConfiguration`, but without any luck.

Comment: I think that configuration can be set in Spring Boot's `application.yml`

Comment: `application.yml` is for maven, right? I'm not sure gradle (or kotlin gradle dsl) pulls that in?

Comment: Nevermind! `application.yml` is right, it's not a maven concept, it's a Spring Boot concept so it works. Nice, thanks @aSemy

Answer (score 0):

you can configure properties in the applciation.yml file or application.properties whatever is relevant in your case. Since you are using spring boot, DGS will pick up properties from your application properties file.